# Database for Web Application

Tags: mysql, database, web-applications, firebird

I want to start a web project in **ASP.Net** and still not decided which database to use. I have had experience with MSSQL and Oracle, but I want one that is free to the end user.

My options are: **MySQL, Firebird and PostgreSQL.**

What do you recommend and why?

Thanks for the support.

Comment: Stack Over Flow is not a recommendation engine but I prefer PostgreSQL.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. "Shopping list" questions are not appropriate here. There are Meta posts [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139618/172661) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/158809/172661) that explain the reasons. We also don't do general recommendations. If you have a specific question about the database engines, you should ask that question. Voting to close as "not constructive". Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used MySql, PostgreSql, and MS Sql extensively. I would recommend MySql. It is easy to set up and configure, has all the features you will need, and is used by countless open source projects across the world, including Wordpress, which a ridiculous number of people use to power their websites.

I would use PostgreSql if you need more powerful and fine-grained support. It has been around a long time along with it's ancestors, and at one point powered the largest database in the world, a 2 petabyte database run by Yahoo.

For a simple web app, though, I would recommend MySql. It is used by more people, and is the de facto open source database.